# Preview different then output in views

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms, nodes

I'm a newbie in drupal. So I have this view which Im saving as a block and the way it displays in the preview of the view and on the page is different. Any ideas?

If you have any questions about my configuration just ask I didn't know what to include :)

Comment: How are they different? The data is different? The appearance is different? Something not working?

Answer (score 1):

This displays data after all the filters, arguments, etc are applied. It's kind of like the raw output. You're theming will be displayed when the actual page is loaded with the block enabled for that page.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell from only this amount of information, because modules and themes can significantly (or completely) alter the appearance of your output, which can cause surprises and anger and facepalms (see my example), but **one reason (out of the many)** for Views preview differing from the output ***can* be** - on a multilingual site - that **you have already translated your views pages and fields via** [**i18nviews** (Internationalization Views)](https://drupal.org/project/i18nviews).

I'll write down my case, maybe it spares some time for anyone else suffering from a ridiculously trivial, but not too "eye-catching" problem.
I rewrote the output of a field like this:

[image: Rewrite the output of this field]

And I didn't understand why my fields appear well in the preview area, get the divs, the classes, etc., but I see a result which is totally different, no divs, no extra classes. As it turned out, the source of the problem is that I watched the page in another language (not the same as I watched when inspecting the preview results), and unfortunately the field has formerly been ***translated*** via i18nviews (with which most of the Views fields can be translated) like this:

[image: Rewrite the output of this field - translated]

This way it didn't get the appropriate divs and classes.
I had to copy the exact same markup of *"Rewrite the output of this field"*, save the translation, problem solved.
But I had to spend half an hour to find out the reasons. This may sound silly, but situations like this can occur while developing. If it saved some time for anyone, it was worth writing it down.