# How exactly does a View Preview differ from what is rendered on a page/block?

Tags: 7, views

There are a [number](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/25726/39617) [of](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/72628/39617) [questions](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/156658/39617) relating to this issue. I'm interested in a general explanation so I can troubleshoot why my complex (contextual filters, relationships, etc) view preview would be working as expected while the view block shows different results.

What exactly is being run for the preview compared to the normal display of the view? What happens 'after' the preview, or are these different paths/processes/methods/hooks altogether?

Comment: The them layer is the most likely culprit: in the preview you are probably running under an administration theme: your site theme could be doing any number of things that would alter output. Have you tried switching site theme to Bartik, to see if that makes a difference?

Answer (score 1):

If aggregation is enabled and query settings distinct and/or pure distinct as well with flags relationships, I experienced differences in what the preview was showing and what showed in the actual block/page version. The solution for me was disabling the distinct option.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is likely related to the contextual filter. If the data you are supplying to the preview doesn't match the data provided from the url, etc. then the results will differ.

Comment: Isn't that what the 'Preview with contextual filters' box is for?